# npm install can't resolve git repositories - certificate failure

Tags: node.js, git, ssl, certificate, npm

I have a nodejs project with a package.json file (on ubuntu). Some dependencies in the package.json file pointing to **git-repositories** (gitlab with a self signed certificate).

If I call

```
npm install
```

npm should resolve and install all dependencies. Unfortunatly I have the following error message:

```
npm ERR! git clone https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git Cloning into bare repository '/home/dev/.npm/_git-remotes/https-git-repository-domain-com-myname-grunt-grunticon-hover-git-15073ad9'...
npm ERR! git clone https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git 
npm ERR! git clone https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none while accessing https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
npm ERR! git clone https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git fatal: HTTP request failed
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: error: server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none while accessing https://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

If I clone the repository with "git clone ..." I have no problems.

Do I have to install a certificate? How can I install the certificate? Where do I find the certificate?

I am using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

use git+ssh in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "myname": "git+ssh://git.repository.domain.com/myname/grunt-grunticon-hover.git"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly Our server doesn't support git+ssh

Comment: I have no experience with https so can't say anything about that method but you may have to support ssh and have the certificate on the machine that you're installing the modules on.

Comment: "git+https://..." isn't working if I use "npm install". It works if I use "git clone https://..."

Comment: have you added your public ssh-key to your gitlab profile? (you can find that under "My Profile"